# Debugging hotkey collisions - a XAML with all included views?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm maintaining a large c# XAML-based UI project which uses several embedded common or at least reused XAML controls. As in, like,

`<shared:DirectionsView DataContext="{Binding DirectionsViewModel}"/>`

The problem comes when I try to define hotkeys for new buttons in one UI that happen to already be in use in some included control. I can see the embedded control directly in the XAML editor, but if I want to add ALT+V as a hotkey somewhere, searching the XAML I'm editing for "_v" isn't going to find something in the DirectionsView that's hotkeyed that way.

Is there some file, maybe generated during the build process, that is the "final XAML" or otherwise represents the form with all inclusions in it? That way I'd at least have something to probe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some file, maybe generated during the build process, that is the "final XAML" or otherwise represents the form with all inclusions in it?

No, there isn't. The visual tree is composed at runtime when the XAML processor parses the BAML (the compiled XAML) and actually creates instances of the runtime classes such as your `DirectionsView` class.

So you will have to search through the different source files and compose your own "final" element tree "manually" I am afraid.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much when I couldn't find any likely candidates in the generated view code. That's unfortunate. Thanks though.